# How to make Parent Job fail if either of the two child jobs fail in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have the following setup in Jenkins:

The BuildFlow BF-A, BF-B, and BF-C all kick-off two job (X and Y).
We need to implement a change where the Flow (BF-A, BF-B, BF-C) should fail when either of the two jobs (X or Y) fail.

would the following work? :

Use Parametrized Trigger Plugin.

With it you can add substeps named Trigger/call builds on other projects which will fail your master job if they fail themselves.

Would this work with BuildFlow jobs ?

Comment: BF-A, BF-B, and BF-C are different flows?

Comment: Yes, they are : BuildGateFlow, StagingGateFlow, and IntegrationGateFlow respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In those cases I use multijob plugin.
create a multi-job job (for example BF-a). then configure it like this:

1. in cases X and Y runs in parallel, create a multijob phase with 2 jobs
   [image]

In this case the phase would stop if one of the jobs fails,because "kill the                             phase on" is set to "failure". 
The "Continuation condition to next phase" option should be set to "Successfull", so the parent job will not continue to the next phase if the current phase failed, marking itself as failed.

2. In case X and Y runs sequentially, create 2 different multijob phases and put the sub jobs in the required order. then set the "kill the phase" and "Continuation condition" options.
   [image]

for more information about multijob plugin see https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin